# Weight load of a hanging 2x4 shelf

Tags: wood

I am looking to hang a shelf from the ceiling of my garage between two garage doors.  The shelf is 32" x 94" and made from a frame of 2x4 and 3/4 plywood on top.  I've tried to weigh it and I think it weighs approx. 63lbs.  One end of the shelf can be directly screwed into the stud of the garage wall.  The other end (and another mid way) would be screwed to the ceiling joist using 4 2x4 screwed into the shelf and then into the ceiling.  I was thinking of using L brackets with lag bolts to fix the shelf to the ceiling.  I was planning on using #8 3" wood screws to attach the 2x4 that will hang the shelf.  Am I way off or will this hold?

---

The ceiling joists I am attaching to are 2x4 on end that span approx. 6-7'.  They are notched at the ends where both ends sit on the bottom sill of I beams.  The I beams span the width of the garage (approx. 23') and sit on a stack of 5 2x4 standing on end.  Thank you for your input.

It is possible to get above the I beams but it would entail taking down drywall and then replacing.  I was hoping for the shelf to support approx. 250-300 lbs total.

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to answer this (what will the shelf hold, weight-wise) without knowing what your garage ceiling joists are, if they are part of a truss or just joists, how long the span is, and really, what they were designed to hold up in the first place - many garage ceiling joists are barely in spec to hold drywall, much less a load...

A FAR better attachment method is to place a beam (or more than one) inside the "attic" space across the top of the joists, spanning several, and run threaded rod (steel) through that beam and down through the ceiling to support the item below. In this case it would mean you can spread the load across many more joists (by using a long beam in the attic space.) It also means that you are not depending on wood screws to hold the load directly.

Comment: +1 for stating that the framing probably won't safely support much weight.